# Will tensor calculus be still valid if the metrilinic property is violated?

Tags: tensors

Given covariant basis $\mathbf{Z}_{i}$ and covariant derivative $\nabla_{k}(\cdot)$, the metrilinic property, i.e.,

$$\nabla_{k}\mathbf{Z}_{i} = 0,$$
is a critical aspect of tensor calculus (at least in view of GR). But I am not sure whether I have got all of its implications. I have vaguely heard that if this property violates, say , $\nabla_{k}\mathbf{Z}_{i} \neq 0$, GR does not hold anymore. But, forgetting about GR, I am curious about what would happen to the correctness of the theory of tensor calculus if the cited voiolation $\nabla_{k}\mathbf{Z}_{i}\neq 0$ does indeed occur. In particular, does tensor calculus formalism (regardless of its applicability to GR) and results still stand if one violates the metrilinic property?

(This question is raised based on my thoughts to use tensor calculus in an engineering modeling problem in which the lengths of its covariant bases may vary with respect to time. So, I am interested in knowing the impact of considering $\nabla_{k}\mathbf{Z}_{i}\neq 0$ on the remainder of tensor calculus in this case.)

Comment: Could you provide a rigorous definition of metrilinc? What is $\mathbf{Z}_i$?

Comment: @Deane: Please check the edited question, whose first part now defines metrilinic property in a more rigorous manner.

Comment: How is a covariant basis defined? Isn't the vanishing of the covariant derivative part of the definition?

Comment: @user3257842: A covariant basis is a unit vector associated with a coordinate system. Vanishing covariant derivate is indeed a part of the definition of the metrilinic property, as noted above. But it is not a part of the definition of covariant basis (at least to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: One can do tensor calculus on any manifold equipped with an affine connection, be it the Levi-Civita connection of some metric or not. See e.g. the first couple of chapters in "Geometry VI: Riemannian Geometry" by Postnikov.

Comment: Then the metrilinic  property is a property of the basis you've $Z_{i}$ you've chosen to do the computations in.  There always exists at least one basis with the metrilinic property, at least in Riemann geometry, However you could also use a "wrong" basis that is of unit-vectors yet lacks the metrilinic property with respect to your metric. 
https://www.physicsforums.com/attachments/ethetahat-jpg.191594/ 

What you would get is probably a torsion tensor
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_tensor 
tough I'm not sure.

Comment: The point being, the metrilinic  property is not intrinsic to the geometry of the manifold (ie. space-time). It's a property of the "frame of reference" which you've chosen to measure space-time with. And  "frames of references" are chosen with said property because they're easier to calculate with. You're only dealing with distortions introduced by the space-time geometry (intrinsic), not with additional ones introduced by you coordinate system.  As pointed out by @IvoTerek, it's possible to do tensor calculus in a coordinate-independent manner, ie. without using a frame of reference at all.

Comment: @user3257842: I feel a bit lost here. What do you mean by "in a coordinate-independent manner"? Tensor calculus needs to define covariant bases that are representatives of coordinates. So, can you explain how can one do tensor calculus in a coordinate-independent way?

Comment: I usually work using Ricci_calculus and coordinate charts.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_calculus
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold#Coordinate_charts

A chart maps a region of our $n$-dimensional manifold to an open subset of $R^n$
We have the metric tensor $g_{ab}$ defined for every point of our chart.  This allows us to convert between distances on our chart and distances on the manifold.

Comment: Different charts of the same manifold can give us different coordinate metrics, but they all represent the same  metric on the manifold, and are related by coordinate transformations. They are not unlike the different map projections used to represent the earth.  https://www.joaoleitao.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/world-map-projections-1024x903.jpg

If you want, you can endow your coordinate metric with frames, but usually the chart is enough to to calculations.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Metric_in_coordinates